# PyCharm/robotframework-lsp running system interpreter instead of venv

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I have a problem running my code under PyCharm. I have selected my venv as the interpreter but when I run os.system(command), PyCharm uses the python installation path instead of the venv path. The code is a Robot Framework library.

```
import os, platform
from robot.api.deco import keyword


@keyword
def download_driver(browser="chrome"):
    browser = browser.lower()
    if browser == "gc":
        browser = "chrome"
    elif browser == "ff":
        browser = "firefox"

    command = f"webdrivermanager {browser}"
    if platform.system() == "Linux":
        link_path = "$HOME/.local/bin"
        command = f"{command} --linkpath {link_path}"
    os.system(command)
```

When I run it using terminal (with activated venv) then everything runs fine, but when I run it from PyCharm I get the message below:

```
'webdrivermanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The library is in the path:

[image: Python interpreter]

Comment: Not sure if this will work but you could try to add the path to the venv at the top of the script using `sys.path.insert`. (More specifically, the path should probably point to the directory where 'webdrivermanager' can be found!)

Comment: Sadly, it didn't help.

Comment: what commands do you run in the terminal when it works?

Comment: Also, with your env activated, can you run `webdrivermanager` in the terminal? What does `whch webdrivermanager` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found what is causing the problem and a workaround:

- It's the Robot Framework template, that is not using my venv (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16086-robot-framework-language-server),
- If I run my code from Python configuration template, everything works fine, but Robot Framework debugger doesn't work.

Python template:
[image]

Robot Framework template and plugin settings look fine, so I assume it's a bug:
[image]

[image]